# Change python 2.7 default gcc 5.4 to gcc 7

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04, gcc

I just upraded gcc from 5.4 to 7 but, when i run python 2.7 it says:

> Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 20 2017, 18:23:56)
>   [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2

I set gcc 7 as default for my system Ubuntu 16.04 and i want to set it as default for python too, how can i achive this configuration?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the version with which python was compiled, not your current gcc version.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, i have learned something new =)